# Editing the WSDL generated by a web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl, editing

I have a basic web service that parses XML sent from a client. The web service works fine but I was asked to remove elements from the WSDL file generated by the web service. Is it even possible to do this?

Here are the first lines from the WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="localhost">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="localhost">
      <s:element name="HTTPWebService">
        <s:complexType/>
     </s:element>
     <s:element name="HTTPWebServiceResponse">
       <s:complexType>
         <s:sequence>
           <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HTTPWebServiceResult">
             <s:complexType mixed="true">
               <s:sequence>
                 <s:any/>
               </s:sequence>
             </s:complexType>
           </s:element>
         </s:sequence>
       </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
   </s:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="HTTPWebServiceSoapIn">
   <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HTTPWebService"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Is it possible to remove the lines `<s:element name="HTTPWebServiceResponse">` and it's contents, and `<s:element name="HTTPWebServiceResponse">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL is a system generated xml file and editing its content may cause unexpected behavior and may not be load during introspecting. You cannot edit those lines without understanding what functionality these elements do.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought, too.